# How to insert data into multiple php sql tables with foreign keys?

Tags: php, html, sql, database, authentication

I am looking to run three sql queries to insert 3 sets of data into 3 different sql tables for a login/reg system. I need to be able to update all three tables at once whilst keeping all keys accurate and up to date. Im able to get two tables working but my login table wont allow any info to be inserted.

Any help will be useful :)

PHP CODE:

```
if ($password == $password2){
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO customer(FirstName, SecondName, Address, EmailAddress, TelephoneNumber) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$address', '$email', '$telephonenumber')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $CustomerID = mysqli_insert_id($db);

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO login(CustomerID, Username, PassW) VALUES ('$CustomerID', '$username', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql2);


        $sql3 = "INSERT INTO inkstyle(CustomerID, Colour, Blackwork, Realism, Traditional, Japanese, Watercolour) VALUES ('$CustomerID', '$colour', '$blackwork', '$realism', '$traditional', '$japanese', '$watercolour')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql3);
```

My html code is fine in terms of buttons and text boxes.

Here are the variable ive declared before the if statment:

```
 $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
$password= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);
$password2= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password2']);
$firstname= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['firstname']);
$surname= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['surname']);
$address= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['address']);
$email= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
$telephonenumber= mysqli_real_escape_string($db,      $_POST['telephonenumber']);

$colour= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb1']);
$blackwork= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb2']);
$realism= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb3']);
$traditional= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb4']);
$japanese= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb5']);
$watercolour= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['cb6']);
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Above code does not work?

Comment: Data is inserted into both the customers table and inkstyle table with the correct customerIDs but the login table wont show anything

Comment: The issue looks like with your query. Please double check the spelling of your login table fields.

Comment: Have you verified the values of `$CustomerID`, `$username`, and `$password` immediately before you use them in your string?

Comment: Does the query generates an error, warning or anything? It's perhaps about your query and/or your table.

Comment: No warning message Ant, everything goes through fine. Just nothing is in the login table

Comment: You're not exactly _checking_ for any messages though.  You're not checking the result of `mysqli_query($db, $sql2);` and you're not making use of [mysqli_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it bois. It was because i was hashing the password but i didnt set enough characters in the sql table :) thanks for the help!